# Proof of Sobolev Inequality Theroem

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces

I have a short question about the proof of Theorem 2 below. I have included Theorem 1's statement since it is used in the proof of Theorem 2.

**Definition**: If $1 \leq p < n$, the Sobolev Conjugate of $p$ is $p* := \frac{np}{n-p}$, note that p* > p.

Consider the following two Theorems related to Sobolev Inequalites:

**Theorem 1(Gagliardo-Nirenberg-Sobolev inequality)**
Assume $1\leq p<n$. There exists a constant $C$, depeding only on $p$ and $n$, such that $||u||_{L^{p*}(\mathbb{R}^{n})} \leq C||Du||_{L^{p}(\mathbb{R}^{n})}$ for all $u \in C_{c}^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$.

Where in the proof of Theorem 1 it is determined that $C = \frac{p(n-1)}{n-p} = p* - \frac{p}{n-p}$.

**Theorem 2**
Assume $U$ is a bounded open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Suppose $u \in W_{0}^{1,p}(U)$ for some $1 \leq p < n$. Then we have the estimate $||u||_{L^{q}(U)} \leq C||Du||_{L^{P}(U)}$ for each $q \in [1,p*]$, the constant $C$ depending only on $p,q,n$ and $U$.

**Proof**:
Since $u \in W_{0}^{1,p}(U)$, there exist functions $u_{m} \in C_{c}^{\infty}(U)$ ($m=1,2...$) converging to $u$ in $W^{1,p}(U)$. We extend each function $u_{m}$ to be 0 on $\mathbb{R}^{n}-\bar{U}$ and apply Theorem 1 to discover $||u||_{L^{p*}(U)} \leq C||Du||_{L^{p}(U)}$. As $|U| < \infty$, we furthermore have $||u||_{L^{q}(U)} \leq C||u||_{L^{p*}(U)}$ if $1 \leq q \leq p*$. $\square$

How does the final part of the proof follow? The part which states "...As $|U| < \infty$, we furthermore have $||u||_{L^{q}(U)} \leq C||u||_{L^{p*}(U)}$ if $1 \leq q \leq p*$."

Thanks for any assistance. This proof is from book 'Partial Differential Equations' by Lawrence Evans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generalized Holder will do the trick, taking the $L^r$ norm of the indicator on $U$ and the $L^{p\ast}$ norm of $u$. Note the inequality needs $1/q=1/p\ast + 1/r$ which shows what range of $q$ this applies to.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Would you be able to give some detail regarding how you would apply this, I'm not quite following the described method.

Comment: @JohnDo Yes the q norm of the product of $u$ and $1_U$ (which is just $u$)  is bounded by the $r$ norm of the indicator (picks up the measure of $U$ to the 1/r power) and the p* norm of u, see http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hölder's_inequality   for generalization

Comment: Thanks for response, yes I see how the inequlaity follows for some constant $C$ but how does it follow for this particular constant C which also holds for $||u||_{L^{p*}(U)} \leq C||Du||_{L^{p}(U)}$. I don't think I made my question clear enough. I have added some more detail to the proofs and included a definition as well. What I want to know is how does it follow that the two inequalites $||u||_{L^{p*}(U)} \leq C||Du||_{L^{P}(U)}$ and $||u||_{L^{q}(U)} \leq C||u||_{L^{p*}(U)}$ have the same constant $C$? Are they necessarily considered to be the same constant?

Comment: no but usually you just take the maximum so the same constant works everywhere

Comment: Okay that's what I thought. Thanks for assistance. Have you read the book 'Partial Differential Equations' by Lawrence Evans from which this proof is taken?

Answer (score 0):

I am currently also working through the subject of Sobolev Spaces using the same recommended book by Evans. Afer the result of your Theroem 2 it says the following in the book "In view of Theorem 2 on $W_{0}^{1,p}(U)$ the norm $||DU||_{L^{p}}$ is equivalent to $||u||_{W^{1,p}(U)}$, if $U$ is bounded." Do you know the argument behind this statement? It's on page 266.