# Sobolev spaces necessary and sufficient condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces

I am studying PDE now using mostly Evan's book. I have been thinking about the following problem and I don't know whether there is a solution or not.

**Problem Formulation:** Let $A$ be a subset of $R^n$. Assume further $A$ is both open and bounded. Let $a \in L^p(A)$ where $1<p<\infty$ and $A$ has $C^1$ boundary. Can we find a sufficient and necessary condition such that $a \in W_0^{1,p}$.
I was motivated by inequalities http://www.cims.nyu.edu/~chou/notes/pde11 in the end of this material and by the MathSE post [Proof of Sobolev Inequality Theroem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/533187/proof-of-sobolev-inequality-theroem).

Maybe this is well know fact, sorry if it is.

Comment: I am confused. Is $a$ a subset of $R^n$ or a function?

In any case, there is a definition of the space $W_0^{1,p}$ in the notes you linked to. Are you looking for an equivalent definition?

Comment: If $A$ has Lipschitz boundary, then $a\in W^{1,p}_0$ iff $\text{trace}\, a =0$. Without boundary regularity you need that $a$ has to be in the closure of $C_c^\infty(A)$ with respect to the $W^{1,p}$ norm. But both ways are essentially the definiton of $W_0^{1,p}$

Comment: @user49048 a is a function. I know the definition of $W_0^{1,p}$, but I am just trying to see if I could define it using some inequalities

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 I think I should add the boundary regularity as well, and thnx for the hint. I will edit my problem now.

Comment: Maybe Inequalities with Sobolev Conjugates like this one http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/569111/using-the-extension-operator-theorem-for-sobolev-spaces

Comment: or inequalities involving Holder's Conjugate